# Bootstrap Maximum number of columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the maximum number of columns in bootstrap?

Can I increase it to have unlimited or 30/40 columns on a single page?

thanks everyone for answers, can anyone please include a quick fiddle as it will help others (I am very stupid)

Comment: You can nest columns within columns so there isn't a theoretical limit but there will obviously be a practical limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap's standard grid is based on 12 columns.  Each column, however, can be split into up to 12 sub-columns and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the number of columns in bootstrap by downloading a customizable version and setting @grid-columns to your desire value. You can change that here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system